# Not getting the right values the sort array method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hello I am not really sure why I am not getting the right values, here's an example.It is a basic question but I am not sure if this happened before...

```
const arr = [4,1,9,5,6]; 
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    console.log(a);
});
```

I should be getting:

// output: 4,1,9,5,6

Instead I am getting:

// output: 1,9,5,6

I remember the first value in this case "a" used to show all the items in the array. did it change?

Comment: 1) Please try to pick a more descriptive title. 2) What browser/version do you see this behavior on? I tested this in FF 64 and Chrome 71 and got `4 1 9 5 6` on both.

Comment: Don't try to predict which elements will be tested in which order in a `sort`. (also, elements may well be tested more than once) Use a standard array iteration method instead, if you want to log in order.

Comment: @MarlonParraRuiz—the compare function returns the same value for every comparison. In that case, the order is not guaranteed to be stable (i.e. preserved), so elements **may** not remain in their original positions (or they might).

Comment: @p.s.w.g I am asking this because I am following a tutorial about the array sort method and in the example he was console logging the a value to see what it returns and he got all the iterations and I got a different iteration that's why I am wondering whats going on... i am using the lastest google chrome version but I don't think it's the browser version since in the tutorial he is also using of the latest versions of google chrome...

Answer (score 2):

Your are doing a `console.log` from the **comparison predicate**. You have no guarantee of the order of application of this function on your data.

The order of output depends both on your array ordering **and** on the underlying sorting algorithm used by `sort`.

There are many sorting algorithms, such as bubble sort, selection sort, quick sort... which could apply the predicate in different orders.

Comment: I think this is close. The key can be found in the [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort): "*The elements of this array are sorted. The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order)*". In this case, every comparison will return *undefined*, so the result might be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You comparison function always returns void. It needs to return > 0 for a is greater than b, 0 if they are equal and < 0 if b is greater.

```js
const arr = [4,1,9,5,6]; 
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback inside the sort function is used when you would like to write your own comparator logic. Try to understand the working of `compareFunction`-

> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>     elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>     behavior, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back
>     to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If
>     inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.
>
> Source-
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: The above cases don't cover where the *comparefn* returns the same value for every comparison. In that case, order may not be preserved.